# Center the plot title in ggsurvplot

Tags: ggplot2, themes, center, title, survival-analysis

I'm struggling with getting my plot title to the center using ggsurvplot...

I've seen some posts mentioning something like `xxxx$plot + theme(....)`
but this solution does not seem to work for me.

Here's my code, maybe you can see what I'm missing:

```
surv_object_CA19.9 <- Surv(time = data_OS$OS_Days / 30, event = data_OS$Status.Death)
CA19.9_surv_fit <- survfit(surv_object_CA19.9 ~ CA19.9.initial_status, data = data_OS)

CA19.9_OS <- ggsurvplot(CA19.9_surv_fit, data = data_OS, pval = TRUE, xlab = "Time [Months]", 
           ylab = "Overall survival", risk.table = TRUE, legend.title = "", 
           risk.table.col. = "strata", risk.table.y.text = FALSE, surv.scale = "percent", 
           break.x.by = 6, xlim = c(0, 60), legend.labs = c("Pathological", "Normal"), 
           title = "Overall survival for patients with initially pathological or normal CA19-9 values", 
           CA19.9_OS$plot + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)))
```

Thank you for any help! I'm still new to R and not particularly a friend of it yet, so any tips are highly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks, @chemdork123, it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One relatively easy solution is to define your own [custom theme](https://joeystanley.com/blog/custom-themes-in-ggplot2) based off of the theme that is used in `ggsurvplot()`.  Looking at [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survminer/versions/0.4.7/topics/ggsurvplot) for the function shows us that it is applying via `ggtheme=` the theme `theme_survminer()`.  We can create a custom function that uses `%+replace%` to overwrite one of the theme elements of interest from `theme_survminer()`:

```
custom_theme <- function() {
  theme_survminer() %+replace%
    theme(
      plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5)
    )
}
```

Then, you can use that theme by association with the `ggtheme=` argument of `ggsurvplot()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(survminer)

require("survival")
fit<- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, title='Awesome Plot Title', ggtheme=custom_theme())
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to center the "main" title without centering the table titles?

Answer (score 1):

```
#Add parameters to your theme as follows
centr = theme_grey() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"))

#Fit the model
fit<- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

#create survival plot
ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, title="Your Title Here", ggtheme=centr)
```

[image: output]